# VBA: Filtering a list and storing result as named ranges

Tags: vba, named-ranges

I have the following list:

[image]

I want to make a VBA code filtering the different names on which store they work in, and storing the result in a named range with the name of the store - and the range being the names from the list working in that store.

For example, the named ranges would be London - containing cells B2 and B7, and so on.

**EDIT**:

I know this is wrong, but I just cannot solve this. VBA is just not what I want it to be at the moment... I first made a new column of the named ranges, and then proceeded.

[image]

```
Sub NamedRange()

Dim arr() As Variant

arr = Sheet1.Range("D2:D4").Value

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer
    Dim Name As String
    Dim k1 As Range, k2 As Range

    Lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    i = 0

    Do While i < 4
    Name = arr(i)
    For j = 1 To Lastrow
    k1 = Match(arr(i), Cells(i, 1).Value, 0)
    k2 = Union(k1, k2)

    Next j

    Range(k2).Select
    Application.Goto Reference:=arr(i)

    Loop


End Sub
```

**EDIT2**: Spent two hours trying to understand the AdvancedFilter function. Made it work using x1FilterCopy option, but my whole Excel-sheet will be a mess this way. Is there any way of filtering and just storing the filtered range in a variable. God, VBA, why are you made this way?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Scott Craner: Yes, of course. But I really do not know how to attack this. I imagine I need to figure out how to store each department in some array (how I'm not sure), and then make a for loop for each object in the array where I somehow filter the desired cells from the first column and store what I filtered in a named range. I'm just completely new to this VBA and cannot think straight.

Comment: That is exactly how to do it.  So google each part individually, try to put them together.  Then come back with your code when you encounter a specific problem.  Note: The named range will work till someone sorts the data, then you will need to redo the range names.  so you will want to search worksheet change events also.

Comment: @ScottCraner: I'll keep googling then. What do you mean "till someone sorts the data..."? A named range is just a string with a bunch of cells you want to remember, right?

Comment: Yes but what happens when the sheet on which the data exists is sorted, the named range stays referring to the same cells on the sheet but the data in those cells are now different. Thus messing up the output.  Depending on your desired output you may want to try a different method.

Comment: @ScottCraner I've tried as you see above, but I just do not know... I do not know what functions to use, or how to use them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

Note that, as said above, using named ranges this way is probably not the best approach.

It may be better to explain your end goal (because you can filter the data and manipulate it from there).

That being said, this does what you are looking for.

For Each cell in `B2:B10`, we are going to see if a named range exists for that value.

If a named range does not exist, we create one.

If one does exist, we union the two ranges.

Then, we can click on our departments and select the ranges by grabbing their value.

Copy and paste this macro and run `NameTheRanges`

You can then add event code to sheet one to select ranges when you click on the department.

```
Sub NameTheRanges()

ClearAllNamedRanges 
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Range("B2:B10")
    If Not DoesNamedRangeExist(c.Value) Then
        c.Offset(0, -1).Name = c.Value
    Else
        Union(Range(c.Value), c.Offset(0, -1)).Name = c.Value
    End If
Next c

End Sub

Function DoesNamedRangeExist(NR As String) As Boolean
Dim checker As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set checker = Range(NR)
On Error GoTo 0
If checker Is Nothing Then
    DoesNamedRangeExist = False
Else
    DoesNamedRangeExist = True
End If
End Function

Sub ClearAllNamedRanges()
Dim NR
For Each NR In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    NR.Delete
Next
End Sub
```

Event code to select ranges (This goes in the sheet you are using - Sheet1 in my case):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Sub
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E2:E4")) Is Nothing Then Range(Target.Value).Select

End Sub
```

Results When I click Liverpool (In Cell `E3`).

[image: Click Liverpool]

Name Manager Results:

[image: Name Manager Results]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer! I will try and understand what you have written.

Comment: No problem :) If you have multiple worksheets, you may want to specify the sheet names (Instead of using `Range("B2:B10")` you would want to use `Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B10")` or something along those lines.

Comment: Thank you! I'm having some problem with the *c.Offset(0, -1).Name = c.Value* line. Some "illegal name error" (I am not on English Excel). It worked fine with my example document (liverpool , london etc), but when moved to real data this error stops everything. Any idea?

Comment: Do you have special characters in your names? Named ranges can't contain special characters.

Comment: Also, make sure that you're not reading through column A because getting a negative column offset from that will look for the column before A which doesn't exist. http://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/568288-named-ranges-what-characters-are-or-are-not-allowed-in-the-nam.html

Comment: Ah you are right, I had special characters! Thank you!