# iltering a list and storing result as named ranges _method Range of _global Failed

Tags: excel, vba

I've used the code from this question:
[VBA: Filtering a list and storing result as named ranges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33304029/vba-filtering-a-list-and-storing-result-as-named-ranges) but it gave error 1004.

```
Dim DoesNamedRangeExistFlag As Boolean

Sub NameTheRanges()

ClearAllNamedRanges
Dim c As Range
For Each c In Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:B10")

    If Not DoesNamedRangeExist(c.Value) Then
        c.Offset(0, -1).Name = c.Value
    Else
        Union(Range(c.Value), c.Offset(0, -1)).Name = c.Value
    End If
Next c

End Sub

Function DoesNamedRangeExist(NR As String) As Boolean
Dim checker As Range
On Error Resume Next
Set checker = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(NR)

On Error GoTo 0
If checker Is Nothing Then
    DoesNamedRangeExist = False
Else
    DoesNamedRangeExist = True
End If



End Function


Sub ClearAllNamedRanges()
Dim NR
For Each NR In ActiveWorkbook.Names
    NR.Delete
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: On which line does the error occur?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may be attempting an illegal name for the named range.

What is the value of `c` when the error occurs?

If it is, `R` or `C` or anything that already exists as a range reference i.e. `A1` through `XFD1048576` (in 2016), you will get the error described.

`B2:B10` cannot contain something that is a valid cell reference.

The same thing will occur if there are any illegal characters or spaces (at start or within string) in the cell which are not allowed in named ranges e.g if starts with a number.

---

To find out more about naming conventions and illegal names see:

1. [Illegal range names](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2009/04/07/illegal-range-names/)
2. And this excellent resource I just found by Martin Trummer: [Excelnames](https://github.com/MartinTrummer/excel-names/)

Answer (score 0):

My problem was indeed on illegal names , but I caused another issue by changing an option to break on all errors which caused my to halt the whole code even on correct names. so disabling that option and debugging code where it breaks allowed me to fix the codes , thanks a lot for  Qhrr and Mr. Brian i'm sorry it was my first time to post on stackoverflow